# Scroll to newly added element

Tags: jquery

How do I automatically scroll to a newly `.append()`ed element after clicking a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flesler's scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) should do what you want.

```
$().scrollTo( $('div li:eq(14)'), 800 );
```

or if you provide a context..

```
$('.pane').scrollTo('div li:eq(14)')
```

More examples @ http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

### Animated smooth scroll using a jQuery `.scrollintoview` plugin

Visible scrolling is especially essential when there will be more than a pagefull of scrolling. Simply jumping to the element will pose a usability issue and may confuse users. Animation will not because they will know exactly where they are.

```
$("<div>Testung</div>").appendTo("#SomeContainer").scrollintoview();
```

You will find this plugin here:

http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html